# jquery 'remove class' - trying to remove all elements with a particular class

Tags: jquery, removeclass

So I have 2 divs, each with n-elements. 
There are n-pairs of elements across the 2 divs.
Each pair uses the same 'class'.

Is it possible to remove a particular pair at a time? I currently am using the following code:

```
    function leaveGroup(id)
    {

        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        var f = $(e).parentNode;

        // Remove everything with the same class name of the parent
        $('body').removeClass($(f).className);

    }
```

The function isn't working, am I using class names incorrectly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding jQuery.

The [`removeClass`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeClass#class) function removes a class from an existing element.

You want to write the following:

```
var className = $('#' + id).parent().attr('class');
$('.' + className).remove();
```

Note that this won't work if the parent node has multiple classes.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.el').remove() 
// would remove all elements with the 'el' className
```

I believe this is what you want. `removeClass` removes a class. `remove` removes the element.

Answer (score 0):

When you said, remove you want to remove the class of element?
If you want to remove element, you can make this:

> div = document.getElementByClassName('yourClass');

Now you have a collection of itens and now you can remove the item you want, ex:

> div[1].remove();

if you want to remove all at once

> for(i in div){ i.remove();  }